# Angularjs : adding ng-repeat in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am new to angularjs and trying to write a directive. My code for directive is

```
Directives.directive("roleTemplate", function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'EA',
        template : '<div class="box span6">'+
                        '<div class="box-header">'+
                            '<h2 class="custom"><i class="fa-icon-group" style="opacity:.7"></i><span class="break"></span>titile</h2>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="box-content">'+
                            '<p><strong>As a team leader you are likely to...</strong></p>'+
                            '<ul>'+
                                '<li>test</li>'+
                            '</ul>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>',   
        replace : true,
        link : function(scope,element,attr){

        }
    };
});
```

and it works fine when i add

```
<div role-template></div>
```

But when i add ng-repeat to template code which becomes

```
<div class="box span6" ng-repeat = "ob in atWorkObjectsArray">
```

Firfox message popup saying

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost:8080/tm-webapp/resources/lib/angular.js:4678
```

My question is Could this be the problem with ng-repeat, can i use it in template or not?

UPDATA :

```
$scope.atWorkObjectsArray = [$scope.workEffectivenessObj,$scope.workTeamLeadObj];
```

WHERE

```
$scope.workEffectivenessObj = {"title":"Effectiveness", "array":userProperties.atWorkProblmSolving};
```

AND

```
$scope.workTeamLeadObj = {"title":"Team Lead", "array":userProperties.atWorkTeamLead};
```

`atWorkProblmSolving` and `atWorkTeamLead` are javascripts arrays.

and if i use same template code in view (html) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see what is going wrong without the atWorkObjectsArray.
But you can use ng-repeats in directives. Here is my simple example you can use as a guide.

```
    template: '<div> <div ng-repeat="d in data">{{d}}</div></div>'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhC7X/

Comment: i have added more details to question, would you like to view it please.

Comment: It seems like it could be an issue with you data structure. For example, if your struct is somehow circlular there could be issues. If you replace atWorkObjectsArray with some known thing like [1,2] does it work? if so you should see if your data is valid